# 20.04 Add grub-entry to boot a btrfs snapshot

Tags: grub2, btrfs, snapshot

I have install btrfs on my 20.04 system and I created a snapshot named @-2021-04-10 of the root subvolumne named @. Now a want to add a grub menu entry to boot this snapshot. How can I add such a boot entry for grub?

thx
Frank

Comment: You can do this using the tool `efibootmgr`.

Comment: Thx for your feedback. Do you have some more informations e.g. link where a example is explained? I didn't find any informations on this ...

Comment: Took me 5 seconds to find this: https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

Comment: thx, I'm interested in getting a concrete example for using btrfs and a named snapshot to be configured with efibootmgr.